# Setting Sequences of Vertexes in graph

Tags: r, igraph

After extract the authors from metadata of papers, we can build a co-author network which may reveal the academic relations. The authors’ list(auth) just like below, each row is a thesis, each column is an author:

```
> dput(auth)
structure(list(`author 1` = c("Zhang XiaoLin", "Zhang XL", "Zhang ZQ", "Jiansheng Qu", 
"Wang Q", "Wang, XueMei", "ZHANG Lihua", "Jiansheng Qu", "Hui Zhang", "Wang XM"), `author 2` = c("Liu, XiWen", 
"Zhang DR", "Qu JS", "Jingjing Zeng", "Zhang B", "Ma Mingguo", "zhang zhiqiang", 
"Tek Maraseni", "zhang zhiqiang", "Li X"), `author 3` = c("LI Lin", "Zhao Y", 
"Zeng JJ", "Yan Li", "Zhang ZQ", "Li Xin", NA, "Lina Liu", NA, 
"Ma MG"), `author 4` = c("Ceng Yan", "Liang N", NA, "Qin Wang", "Zhang XF", 
"zhang zhiqiang", NA, "Zhiqiang Zhang", NA, "Zhang ZQ")), .Names = c("author 1", "author 2", "author 3", 
"author 4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))
```

I want to build an co-author net with this data frame, my program just like this:

```
# author co-occurrence
library(igraph)
# prepare authors data from metadata of papers
n <- max_n_au
cname <- paste("author", 1:n)
auth <- au_t[, cname]
# function that build the edges of Co-author Relations(CAR)
CAR_edge <- function(au_e) {
  n <- length(au_e)
  if (is.na(auth[,cname])) {
    skip
  } else {
    q <- combn(n,2)
    au_n <- auth[q]
    #dim(au_n) <- dim(q)
  }
  return(au_n)
}
# build author relations for each paper
arp <- lapply(auth, CAR_edge)
Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(auth[, cname])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(auth[, cname])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (is.na(auth[, cname])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (is.na(auth[, cname])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have no experience on making complex functions. Even so, when I test the sentences in the function, I still found that “q” can build a queue for the authors, but it could not pass to the authors correctly. It doesn’t fit in rows but in columns, not complete either. What the mechanism of "`combn()`" function to build a sequence with a data frame. 
I tried to change the method which combn() functions' result to attach authors, but only the way above can run without errors. So I hope I could get some advise on this problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the use of Chinese names a critical part of your problem? If not, I suggest that you change them to `c("A", "B", "C", ... )` in the example. When I ran the dput result in my RStudio environment, I got a load of unicode instead of the Chinese characters. That makes any subsequent code testing much more difficult to read.

Comment: You mean to change the data frame of authors into vector? I do not understand. By the way, on the Simplified Chinese Windows 7, it works but the queue doesn't fit the authors well. If load this program in RStudio, you need to select "file"--"Reopen with Encoding", then select "UTF-8" in the following list. Use this method could open it perfectly. Let's try it.

Comment: I can read Chinese, but SO is an English-based site, so I wouldn't expect everyone else who saw your question to do so. By making it difficult for others to reproduce your problem & check potential solutions, you are reducing the pool of potential SO users who can answer your problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, its my fault. I use the examples from my analysing data directly. I will change it into English by another example asap. Thanks for your suggest!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be simpler.  You just need to construct all possible pairs of author and coauthor from your list. Once you have that, making the graph is easy.

Using your variable `auth` above:

```
## First restructure into a list of pairs
AuthorPairs = data.frame(author = character(), coauthor = character())
for(i in 1:3) { 
    for(j in (i+1):4) {
        AuthorPairs = rbind(AuthorPairs, 
            data.frame(author = auth[,i], coauthor = auth[,j]))
    }
}
AuthorPairs = AuthorPairs[!is.na(AuthorPairs[,2]),]

# Turn it into a graph and plot
library(igraph)

AuthorGraph = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(AuthorPairs), directed=FALSE)
par(mar=rep(1,4))
plot(AuthorGraph, vertex.label.cex=0.8)
```

[image: Author Network]

Comment: Oh, that is a directly realization of co-occurance. In my question, I didn't build co-author network with this method because it may use one or two layers of loops. If it encounter mass data, it may cost much resources in processing. Thank you for your warmly help all the same!